# To introduce loop inside c++ switch- case

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am trying to use this switch - case statement. I was wondering if there is any other efficient way of writing this code. The "function" prototype is: `int function(int a,int b, int c,int d)`

```
switch (u) {
case 1:
  t = t + function(0,2,1,0);   // 1
  break;
case 2:
  t = t + function(0,2,1,0);  // 1
  t = t + function(1,2,2,0);  // 2
  break;
case 3:
  t = t + function(0,2,1,0) ; // 1
  t = t + function(1,2,2,0) ; // 2
  t = t + function(0,3,3,1) ; // 3
  break;
case 4:
  t = t + function(0,2,1,0) ; // 1
  t = t + function(1,2,2,0) ; // 2
  t = t + function(0,3,3,1) ; // 3
  t = t + function(1,3,4,1) ; // 4 
  t = t + function(3,2,4,0) ; // 6
  break;
case 5:
  t = t + function(0,2,1,0) ; // 1
  t = t + function(1,2,2,0) ; // 2 
  t = t + function(0,3,3,1) ; // 3
  t = t + function(1,3,4,1) ; // 4
  t = t + function(2,3,5,1) ; // 5
  t = t + function(3,2,4,0) ; // 6
  t = t + function(4,2,5,0) ; // 7
  break;
case 6:
  t = t + function(0,2,1,0) ; // 1
  t = t + function(1,2,2,0) ; // 2
  t = t + function(0,3,3,1) ; // 3
  t = t + function(1,3,4,1) ; // 4
  t = t + function(2,3,5,1) ; // 5
  t = t + function(3,2,4,0) ; // 6
  t = t + function(4,2,5,0) ; // 7
  t = t + function(3,3,6,1) ; // 8
  break;
case 7:
  t = t + function(0,2,1,0) ; // 1
  t = t + function(1,2,2,0) ; // 2
  t = t + function(0,3,3,1) ; // 3
  t = t + function(1,3,4,1) ; // 4
  t = t + function(2,3,5,1) ; // 5
  t = t + function(3,2,4,0) ; // 6
  t = t + function(4,2,5,0) ; // 7
  t = t + function(3,3,6,1) ; // 8
  t = t + function(4,3,7,1) ; // 9
  t = t + function(6,2,7,0) ; // 11
  break;
case 8:
  t = t + function(0,2,1,0) ; // 1
  t = t + function(1,2,2,0) ; // 2
  t = t + function(0,3,3,1) ; // 3
  t = t + function(1,3,4,1) ; // 4
  t = t + function(2,3,5,1) ; // 5
  t = t + function(3,2,4,0) ; // 6
  t = t + function(4,2,5,0) ; // 7
  t = t + function(3,3,6,1) ; // 8
  t = t + function(4,3,7,1) ; // 9
  t = t + function(5,3,8,1) ; // 10
  t = t + function(6,2,7,0) ; // 11
  t = t + function(7,2,8,0) ; // 12
  break;
}
```

Is there any way to shorten this code?

Every new case has the same function till previous case plus one or two new function.

Ultimate Goal :The goal is to have less code and less manual entry inside the code.

Please do post an answer to decrease the length of code .

All the answers posted till now do not think about automagically creating the numbers themselves as even these numbers have a pattern with them.

Comment: Hint: Assuming `function` has no side-effects, try reversing the order of your statements. Then it'll be obvious how to utilize fall-through.

Comment: It seems some have 2 new functions also.

Comment: @Mysticial but then you'd have to reverse the order in which function() is called.  Might be okay, but might be a deal breaker if it has side effects

Comment: If the new function can be constructed from the previous function, then you may consider using a for loop.

Comment: @Mysticial  : the switch variable 'u' must take values in increasing order from 1 ( case 1,2,3 ... ) and return the values of the variable 't' for each of the case.

Comment: @user2725924 Can you add the definition of `function`? If the function takes constant parameters and has no side-effects, the compiler can detect this and evaluate the function at compile time. This is likely to happen with the example in the question, but unlikely to happen with the example given in the accepted answer.

Comment: @willj: please check this link : http://nrich.maths.org/1388 . I am trying to optimize the switch case statement under checkPoss function.

Comment: @user2725924 You're trying optimize to make it take less time to run? Or to reduce the amount of code duplication? The two goals may conflict with each other. The accepted answer will reduce duplication, but make the code take longer to run.

Comment: @willj: I want to reduce duplication and automate it. The goal is to have less code and less manual entry inside the code. It does not matter if it takes little more time to run. I was trying to use http://www.public.asu.edu/~kburger2/scholar/scramble/Scramble.java    this program as an inspiration. please do check the code after the comment " Called by the controller when the "Solve" button has been clicked. " I am trying to see how it works for a 4*4 and 5*5 and 4*5 puzzle. Please do post an answer 1.) to decrease the length of code and 2.) to increase the size of puzzle from 3*3 to 4*5 .

Comment: @user2725924 Perhaps either edit the question to include this information, or ask a new question. I've added an answer, along with a live demo to prove that it gives the correct result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reduce the amount of code duplication without increasing the time it takes to run, you can use `if` instead of `switch`:

```
assert(u < 9);
if(u >= 1) t = t + function(0,2,1,0) ; // 1
if(u >= 2) t = t + function(1,2,2,0) ; // 2
if(u >= 3) t = t + function(0,3,3,1) ; // 3
if(u >= 4) t = t + function(1,3,4,1) ; // 4
if(u >= 5) t = t + function(2,3,5,1) ; // 5
if(u >= 4) t = t + function(3,2,4,0) ; // 6
if(u >= 5) t = t + function(4,2,5,0) ; // 7
if(u >= 6) t = t + function(3,3,6,1) ; // 8
if(u >= 7) t = t + function(4,3,7,1) ; // 9
if(u >= 8) t = t + function(5,3,8,1) ; // 10
if(u >= 7) t = t + function(6,2,7,0) ; // 11
if(u >= 8) t = t + function(7,2,8,0) ; // 12
```

Comment: @user2725924 Just ask a new question which contains a link back to this question. Unfortunately the problem of increasing the puzzle size is more time consuming to answer than your original question - I may not have time to answer - but I'm sure someone else can!

Comment: @willj: "without increasing the time it takes to run" that's probably not entirely true. you still have 12 conditionals in your code, where the original had only 1. so performancewise, it might be worse than the original. but my solution is probably much worse ;) otherwise it's a real nice solution to avoid duplication!

Comment: @nyarlathotep True, but in the context of the problem being solved I'm confident that an optimal implementation can make `u` a constant. In this case, the conditionals will be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @willj : The second part of my question is too broad as you have mentioned. So, I will try it myself and post a good question if I have  a doubt.

Comment: Note: This solution checks many `if` conditions for great `u` values. For example, for `u=8`, it checks 12 `if` statement while [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19152619/952747) answer checks only one.

Answer (score 12):

Reverse the cases and remove all `break`. Then remove common `+=`:

```
switch (u)
{
case 8:
    t += function(5, 3, 8, 1); // 11
    t += function(7, 2, 8, 0); // 12
case 7:
    t += function(4, 3, 7, 1); // 9
    t += function(6, 2, 7, 0); // 10
case 6:
    t += function(4, 2, 5, 0); // 7
    t += function(3, 3, 6, 1); // 8
case 5:
    t += function(2, 3, 5, 1); // 5
    t += function(4, 2, 5, 0); // 6
case 4:
    t += function(1, 3, 4, 1); // 4 
    t += function(3, 2, 4, 0); // 5
case 3:
    t += function(0, 3, 3, 1); // 3
case 2:
    t += function(1, 2, 2, 0); // 2
case 1:
    t += function(0, 2, 1, 0); // 1
}
```

Comment: Note: my guess too, however it does depend on the order in which `function` is called not to be important.

Comment: Yes, I implicitly assumed `function` hasn't any side effect.

Comment: The "`function`" has to be path-conservative for this to work.  (As soon as I glanced at the code, I thought of this solution.  Maybe I've been doing C++ too long; the `case` reversal was so "obvious" that I suspected that the original poster was a troll.)

Comment: your function does things multiple times - the function call for parameters #5 for u >= 5... also it does not account for the skip of the call with parameters #5 in case u=4 (also missed that in my answer).

Answer (score 8):

One option here would be to create an array of the four possible options to the `function`; and a mapping of which of these parameters to use for any value of `u`.

Then you can do those calls with the mapped parameters in a loop.

Like this:

```
int params[12][4] = {
    {0,2,1,0}, // 1
    {1,2,2,0}, // 2
    {0,3,3,1}, // 3
    // ...
};
vector<vector<int> > paramMapping;
paramMapping.push_back({1});
paramMapping.push_back({{1, 2});
paramMapping.push_back({{1, 2, 3});
paramMapping.push_back({{1, 2, 3, 4, 6});
paramMapping.push_back({{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7});
// .. 

vector<int>::iterator it = paramMapping[u-1].begin();
while (it != paramMapping[u-1].end())
{
     int i = (*it) - 1;
     t += function(params[i][0], params[i][1], params[i][2], params[i][3]);
     ++it;
}
```

This solution, in contrast to the fallthrough-switch in M M.'s answer, would keep the calling order of the `function` calls the same as in your original code (which could be important in case `function` has side-effects, as mentioned in the comments).

The initialisation of the `params` and `paramMapping` should best be done outside of the actual computing function (somewhere in the initialisation of the class that contains the function for example).

**Conclusion:** With the addition of the mapping between number and parameters, this implementation has actually become quite complex, and its debatable whether its simpler than the original switch.

Comment: one of them ;) I don't understand why people immediately downvote - the principal idea was still valid, right?

Comment: Up voted to counter. It is easy to find mistake and point that out then writing a solution yourself :). Still it is important to point out and correct mistakes since the material will be used by those learning from it

Comment: @fayyazkl thanks, and I definitely agree that pointing out mistakes is very important! and even more is correcting them. but downvoting immediately on discovering some mistake is outright impolite in my opinion. why not point out the error, and then wait for a few minutes to give the opportunity to correct...

Comment: @nyarlathotep - my pleasure. It has to do with the way SO is structured in terms of scores. I initially used to do the same i.e. down voting immediately, specially if i answered the question too. It was only after experience that i adopted the correct habit - point out the flaw, and get back to it latter. only down vote if some body refuses to fix the problem where it does exist. This only happens rarely. Also, now i am perfectly happy up voting another answer even if mine has got lower score :). It takes a while to realize the race here is to produce quality content, not point scoring :)

Comment: I downvoted, because an incorrect answer had much higher score than a correct one. Therefore I was trying to counter that.

Comment: @fayyazkl: I see so many questions that I cannot remember which one I had pointed out a flaw in (if the flaw is "worth it"); thus I both downvote and point the flaw, and leave it up to the author to notify me when he has corrected it at which point I remove the downvote (and even maybe upvote).

Comment: Cool - @MatthieuM.and juraj. Both of your above scenarios are fine. I just don't use SO that often. :) and yes if i see a wrong answer getting higher votes, will probably do the same.

Comment: @nyarlathotep : Your answer is almost correct. But, please note that in some cases (case 4 and 7), the last entry jumps by 2. Moreover , I need to return the value of the variable 't' after every case.

Comment: @user2725924 ok that evaded me. then maybe a slightly different approach would be better, namely a mapping from each number to the parameters function needs to be called with for that `u`. I will update my answer soon but actually that really sounds like a very constructed example. what is the underlying problem you're trying to solve here (i.e. what do you compute here)?

Comment: @user2725924 thanks for the link. not sure if my solution then will still be simpler than the original code then... I'll try

Comment: @user2725924 not sure how these relate directly to your question now?

Comment: Yes, it is a bit out of scope of this question. I would like to finish the question here..

Comment: in addition, that is a for loop. Consider to write a for loop instead

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @nyarlathotep, I like the approach of using a map to hold the parameters beforehand.  By using a tuple and std::accumulate you can make the code fairly clean.  No need for the switch statement, just call accumulate to sum up all the functions.  Easy to manipulate if you want to do something other than sum, you could use a for_each and a function of your choice.  I've used C++11 below, but think the idea would work with C++03 and TR1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <tuple>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

int function(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return 1;
}

typedef tuple<int,int,int,int> ParamType;

int addfunc(int a, ParamType b)
{
    return a + function(get<0>(b),get<1>(b),get<2>(b),get<3>(b));
}

int main() {

    map<int, list<ParamType>> params;
    params[1] = {make_tuple(0,2,1,0)};
    params[2] = {make_tuple(0,2,1,0), make_tuple(1,2,2,0)};
    // and so on...

    // later on when you want to use it
    int u = 1;
    int t = 0;
    t = accumulate(params[u].begin(), params[u].end(), t, addfunc);

    return 0;
}
```